# show that f : [a;b] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , an increasing function such that Im f = [f(a);f(b)] is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As said in the title I want to show that  f : [a;b] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an increasing function such that Im f = [f(a);f(b)] is continuous.
In order to do that I proceed by the absurd assuming that f is not continuous on a point c $\in$ [a;b] and  then I defined :

B : = f(a) (if c=a) , B= $lim_{x \rightarrow c^-}$ f(x) = $sup_{x \in [a;b]}$ f(x) (if c $\neq$ a )

and C :=  f(b) (if c=b) , C= $lim_{x \rightarrow c^+}$ f(x) = $inf_{x \in [a;b]}$ f(x) (if c $\neq$ b )

as f is increasing we have f(a) $\leq$ B < C $\leq$ f(b).
But then, I have a hard time expressing the contradiction, I see that there is a problem with ]B;C[ $\cap$ Im f , but not clearly why.

Thank you by advance for your help!

Comment: Do you mean that the image is connected?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745800/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1635426/42969

Comment: The phrase "such that $\text{Im} f = [f(a),f(b)]$ is continuous" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set aside the extremes of the interval, for the moment. As you say, if $c\in(a,b)$, then both the limits from the left and from the right exist and
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\sup\{f(x):a<x<c\},\qquad
\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x):c<x<b\}
$$
Also, since $f$ is increasing, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)\le f(c)\le \lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)
$$
because $f(c)$ is certainly an upper bound of $\{f(x):a\le x<c\}$ and a lower bound of $\{f(x):c<x\le b\}$.

Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $c$. Then one of the limits above is unequal to $f(c)$. Suppose it is the limit from the left. Then we have
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)<f(c)
$$
Take $y$ such that $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)<y<f(c)$. We want to prove that $y$ is not in the range of $f$, after noticing that $f(a)<y<f(b)$, so $y\in[f(a),f(b)]$, which would lead to the desired contradiction.

If $y=f(r)$, for some $r\in[a,b]$, then $r\ne c$, because $f(r)=y<f(c)$. Hence we have either $a \le r<c$ or $c<r \le b$. In the first case $f(r)\in\{f(x):a\le x<c\}$, so $y\le\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)$: a contradiction. In the second case $f(c)<f(r)=y$: a contradiction.

Analogously in the case $f(c)<\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)$. Fix yourself the cases of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit.